# Timestamp of docker container status

Tags: docker

How to get the actual timestamp/date of the startup of docker container(Not when it is created)?

I am fine with getting the date of **CREATED** date with

`docker inspect -f '{{ .Created }}'<container-ID>`

but this is not working for **STATUS**.

I need to know when the service was started last time, not for how long it is up (e.g. Up 4 days).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field you are looking for is `StartedAt` and you can access it by using:

```
docker container inspect -f '{{ .State.StartedAt }}' <container-ID>
```